# How to print JSON values using a loop in Swift 3?

Tags: json, swift

I got this JSON:

```
{
    cover =     {
        id = 1;
};
    description = "Test"
place =     {
        id = 11;
        location =         {
            city = Wheatley;
            };
        name = "Wheatley Provincial Park";
       };
},
{
    cover =     {
        id = 2;
};
    description = "Cool"
place =     {
        id = 22;
        location =         {
            city = Wheatley;
            };
        name = "Wheatley Provincial Park";
       };
}
```

This is my code:

```
 if let fbData = result as? [String : Any] {
    print(fbData)

    for events in fbData {
       print (events["name"] as! String)
        //this displays an error
        //Type (Key: String, value: Any) has subscript members
}
```

}

But I don't know how to loop through them

I already tried these solutions but they never worked:

[JSON Parsing in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155436/json-parsing-in-swift-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Parsing JSON using Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458836/parsing-json-using-swift-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `[String : Any]`: Do you know why you write that? If no, you may want to understand how to read/loop arrays and dictionaries. If yes, JSON are just string, numbers, arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see *real* JSON not just that pseudo-JSON you probably got from the console.

Comment: Is this the real JSON?

Comment: @Mr.UB, some of it. Here is a screenshot of the full http://imgur.com/a/4OQq1.

Comment: So the `result` contain all the content which is shown in the image?? I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if let array = result as? [String : AnyObject]{
    if let fbData = array["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        print(fbData)

        for event in fbData {
            print (event["name"] as! String)
        }
    }
}
```

1. `result` is of  `Any` type
2. Cast it into Dictionary - `[String : AnyObject]`
3. Extract `data` and cast to Array of Dictionaries - `[[String : AnyObject]]`.