# How to get a signal from the JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am fetching the data from the JSON. I want to know how I can fetch the signal value. because as per the signal all the code will work.

`["status": 200, "data": {"in_time" = "12:00 PM"; "out_time" = ""; signal = 01;}, "Message": Enable out time]`

this is code which I am using: Here is all the data which I am using to get the json response

```
    let parameters = ["emp_id": self.att_emp_id]
    var request = URLRequest(url : url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options: [])
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                if let json = json {
                    print("HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON viewdidAppear\(json)")
                    //var datas = [String:AnyObject]()
                    let status = json["status"] as? String
                    if let datas = json["data"] as? [String:AnyObject]  , let in_time_Str = datas["in_time"] as? String, let out_time_Str = datas["out_time"] as? String , let grace_Str = datas["grace"] as? String , let signal_Str = datas["signal"] as? String
                    {
                        self.server_in_time = in_time_Str
                        self.server_out_time = out_time_Str
                        self.grace_str_time = grace_Str
                        self.sig_str = signal_Str
                    }
                    print("Signal : \(String(describing: self.sig_str))")
                    if status == "200" {
                        if self.server_in_time != "" {
                            print("Here is attendance IN TIME : \(self.server_in_time)")
                        }
                        if self.server_out_time != "" {
                            print("Here is attendance OUT TIME : \(self.server_out_time)")
                        }
                        if self.sig_str == "10" {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.out_time_button.isEnabled = false
                            }
                        } else if self.sig_str == "01" {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.inTimeTextField.text = self.server_in_time
                                self.in_time_button.isEnabled = false
                                self.out_time_button.isEnabled = true
                            }
                        } else if self.sig_str == "00" {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.inTimeTextField.text = self.server_in_time
                                self.outTimeTextField.text = self.server_out_time
                                self.in_time_button.isEnabled = false
                                self.out_time_button.isEnabled = false
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Error : \(String(describing: error))")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }).resume()
```

Comment: What is your question? Fetching from API or parsing from above JSON? Is this above your response from Api?

Comment: If you dont mind can you please paste the complete/Valid json here?

Comment: this is the json which i am getting . here i want to get the value "signal" but i am not able to fetch it . others value i am getting but not signal value

Comment: You told others value, can you tell here which value you can parse it?

Comment: Are you parsing data using codable?

Comment: inside data i can fetch the "in_time" value which 12:00 again "out_time" value which is blank . but i cannot get "signal" value which is "01"

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: Signal should be a String then you can retrieve it

Comment: this is not valid json, check with this https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please paste the code that you are trying to get the "signal" value also the "in_time"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a specific value from returned json in Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446479/how-do-i-get-a-specific-value-from-returned-json-in-swift-3-0)

Comment: i have posted the code . there i am not getting the signal value when i print it

Comment: Signal is Integer not string

Comment: no i have confirmed with my backend it is a string .. and the signal value should get before in_time and out_time  and the response is diffferent in android and its different in iOS

Comment: @SandeshZote If you want to handle like a String, use SwiftyJSON for parsing this. `.stringValue`. Otherwise ask your backend team to put the  string value in double quotes("")

Comment: from the json it looks like signal is not a String, can you try something like let signal = datas["signal"] as? Int, let signal_value  = String(signal) {  self. signal_Str = signal_value }

Comment: no not working . the signal value is send in double quotes from backend

Comment: @SandeshZote Then why did you post different JSON format in your question? see your JSON there's no double quotes? Did you try my answer?

Comment: i am trying ur answer only using NSNumber . and this json works in ViewDidload() like every time a view controller is opened it should fetch the signal value and work according to that signal value

Comment: If you want to solve the issue post the real JSON.

Comment: that is the real JSON which i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch, poor you, the giant ant has badly hit you with the curse of the evil `JSONSerialization` (pardon the cheap NetHack rip off). This looks easy at first, but you will have to deal with the curse (cast) of the evil `Optional`/`Any`. You will be much better off (even concerning error messages) if you go with the `Codable` protocol. This will boil down to the following:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
{"status": 200,
   "data": {
        "in_time": "12:00 PM",
        "out_time": "",
        "signal": "01",
    },
"Message": "Enable out time"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct TimeData: Codable {
    let inTime: String
    let outTime: String
    let signal: String

    enum CodingKeys : String,CodingKey {
        case inTime = "in_time"
        case outTime = "out_time"
        case signal
    }
}

struct TimeResult: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let data: TimeData
    let message: String
    enum CodingKeys : String,CodingKey {
        case status, data
        case message = "Message"
    }
}

do {
    let timeData = try JSONDecoder().decode(TimeResult.self, from:jsonData)
    print(timeData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

As you probably notice I had to modify quite a few things with your "JSON" to make this compile.

1. Your top level structure is a `hash`, not an `array`, i.e. your JSON-string should start with a `{` instead of an `[` and finish with a `}` in return.
2. The values in you `data` hash seem to be separated with `=` instead of `:`, this won't be parsed by a standard compliant parser
3. The `key:value` pairs in your `data` hash are separated with `;` instead of `,`, this won't be parsed by a standard compliant parser
4. The `key` part of your `signal` line is not surrounded by `"` to indicate a `String` value this won't be ... (you know the drill by now)
5. The `value` part of your `signal` line is not surrounded by `"` which lets the parser guess it to be a number which results in an illegal condition ("`Number with leading zero around character 103.`").

All these errors (except maybe the first one) are fairly easy to spot if you use a `JSONDecoder` and the appropriate `Codable` protocol for you model. They are however rather hard to spot given the unfortunate `JSONSerialization` which will try (too) hard to make sense of whatever you throw at it ...

And for the record:

```
print(timeData.data.signal)
```

will beautifully access your `signal` in a really straightforward way, even without the excessive use of `if let=...` bindings.

### Addition

After rereading the above I realised, that your "JSON" might have resulted from the way you printed your `data` in the first place. Try using

```
print(String(data:data, encoding:.utf8)!)
```

to find out what your `JSON` *actually* looks like.