# Type Any has no subscript members Error in Swift 3.0?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I am following this [tutorial here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/)...

And the issue I am having is I keep getting the error.

> "Type Any has no subscript members Error" in this function...

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
let todoDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as! NSDate, title: $0["title"] as! String, UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!)}).sort({(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .OrderedAscending)
}
```

The error is being generated on this line...

```
return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as! NSDate, title: $0["title"] as! String, UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!)}).sort({(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .OrderedAscending)}
```

I am completely stumped.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON using Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458836/parsing-json-using-swift-3)

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549107/swift-3-type-any-has-no-subscript-members/39549477#39549477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the type of items object as `[[String:Any]]`.

```
let items = Array(todoDictionary.values) as! [[String: Any]]
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for letting me know what the issue was.